# Armour won't show in my inventory after I pick it up

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

When I pick up daedric boots that I made with the atronach forge under the College of Winterhold, they won't show in my inventory. I've tried exiting the game and reloading a previous save, but it still won't show. What do I do so that they show?

Comment: Are you using any mods?

Comment: Nah i play playstation 3

Comment: Did you drop the boot then pick them up? Because as far I know on the PC version whenever you craft ANYTHING they always end up in your inventory.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunate news, it's an unpatched bug.

According to the [UESP Page on the Atronach Forge](http://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Atronach_Forge), this is a bug present in all versions of Skyrim across all platforms. It was fixed by the PC mod "Unofficial Skyrim Patch v1.2", however you are on PS3, so this does not apply.

The issue, according to the UESP, is that the boots are created as ones worn by the Dremora in the game, and are not a real piece of armor. They will add carry weight to your character, but they will not show up in your inventory, nor are they usable.